# When using MUI Filter List, How do I filter an array with another array within useEffect

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mern, react-hook-form

My fake API contains:

```
export const API_Attachment_Types = [
  { id: "101", name: "PERMIT", description: "Permit"},
  { id: "102", name: "JHA", description: "Job Hazard Analysis"},
  { id: "103", name: "ALC", description: "Access Limitation Certificate"},
  { id: "104", name: "BUC", description: "Box up Certificate"},
  { id: "105", name: "DCONC", description: "De-contamination Certificate"},
  { id: "106", name: "EIC", description: "Electrical Isolation Certificate"},
];
```

I'm using MUI Transfer List within a "React Hook Form" app.
My Transfer list is working and I'm able to save the data back to DB, but am having issues retrieving it back into useEffect hook.

My component code is...

```
  let API_Attachment_right = state.data.packDetail.attachementDetail
    ? state.data.packDetail.attachementDetail
    : [];

  let API_Attachment_left = API_Attachment_Types;

const filterArray = () => {
    return API_Attachment_left.filter((item) =>
      API_Attachment_right.includes(item.id) // I think this needs to loop or something to filter out  already selected items
    );
};

useEffect(() => {
    setLeft(filterArray()); // however I'm unable to filter this by API_Attachment_right items
    setRight(API_Attachment_right); // this works and I'm getting back the data
  }, []);
```

The expected result should be a list on the left that is filtered by the already selected data on the right.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

```
  const filterArray = () => {
    return API_Attachment_left.filter(
      (item) => !API_Attachment_right.find((rm) => rm.id === item.id)
    );
  };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).